# Dashed font style in ArcGIS pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, style, text, font

I am looking to make a dashed font in ArcGIS Pro and cannot seem to find out how to do this anywhere. I am trying to create a map with a felt style, so I would like the text to be dashed (not a dashed outline) to fit the style.

[image]

Comment: Have you installed an appropriate font in Windows? Once you do, it will be usable in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, all you need to do to add new fonts to ArcGIS Pro is [install them in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-font-b7c5f17c-4426-4b53-967f-455339c564c1). If the font is not recognized by Pro after installing in Windows, you can also [add custom fonts by copying the .ttf file to this folder](https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-arcgis-pro-000028024):

```
C:\<your install path to ArcGIS Pro>\Resources\Font
```